# Couchbase server timeout issue in cluster with 2 nodes

Tags: java, couchbase, connection-timeout, membase

We have 2 nodes in the cluster in couchbase which have 4 buckets shared between them, When we are trying to insert data in the buckets using JAVA api we get the following errors :-

```
 `2013-10-08 19:54:29.193 WARN com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Node expected to receive data is inactive. This could be due to a failure within the cluster. Will check for updated configuration. Key without a configured node is: 1.
2013-10-08 19:54:29.499 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@1df749e3
2013-10-08 19:54:29.500 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Reconnecting due to failure to connect to {QA sa=192.168.0.18/192.168.0.18:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:423)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:261)
    at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection.run(CouchbaseConnection.java:288) `

`2013-10-08 19:54:29.502 WARN com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=192.168.0.18/192.168.0.18:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}, attempt 1.
2013-10-08 19:54:33.504 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=192.168.0.18/192.168.0.18:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
```

`

It shows that 'Node expected to receive data is inactive' When it is up and running ... Should we change the RAM quota per bucket (it is very high right now) or Should we reduce the data to be inserted or is it a firewall issue??

Answer (score 1):

It is likely a firewall issue. It appears that you cannot connect to Couchbase and ram quota or amount of data in your Couchbase cluster should not cause slowness. Try connecting to Couchbase port 11211 via telnet from the same machine your client is on. If you cannot telnet to that machine then this would be a strong indication of a firewall issue.

```
telnet <ip address> 11211
```

Comment: Exactly. Solved it .. Thanks